# ms access: how to store the contents of a table in a string array?

Tags: database, ms-access

i'm working on a MS access database..

At some point i needed to create a module which contains a dynamic string array, the data to store in this array should be brought from a table, i use count(*) function on that table to define the size of the dynamic array.

what i need to know is how to fill the array with the contents of a columns of that table ( called Names);

to make it more clear:
suppose i declared the array like this

```
dim myArray() as string
redim myArray(myTable.count(*))
```

where my table contains two fields: ID, Name

i want myArray(0) to hold the content of Name in the first record
       myArray(1) to hold the content of Name in the second record

and so on

how to do this?

Comment: I am curious as to why you would want to do this and not use a recordset instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to use an array, but here is a way adapted from a [Microsoft article](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/a3dbd1bb-dcb6-4a77-ad46-cd5db818c8e6):

```
Dim objConnection as ADODB.Connection
Dim objRecordSet as ADODB.Recordset
Dim arrTest as variant

Set objConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
Set objRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset

objRecordSet.Open "SELECT * FROM YourTable" , objConnection, _
    adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

arrTest = objRecordSet.GetRows

objRecordSet.Close

objConnection.Close
```

Comment: I agree that this is the solution, but, Ala ABUDEEB, why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Remou: because i want my database to be dynamic for users.
It is a simple accounting database, i want to enable the user to add as many accounting sections as he wants without always asking a developer to do that, for example, to add a section for export accounting, and one section miscellanous. so the new accounting section name should be added  to a table, then the array takes these contents and modifies the database as required

Comment: I still do not see why you need the array, can you not simply update the table? I often allow users to add 'sections' with, for example, a combo box and the NotInList event.

Comment: Do not forget that a table can be updated using a query run through VBA: db.Execute "Insert Into TheTable (Section) Values ('" & UsersVal & "')", dbFailOnError

Comment: Assuming using an array is required, which I doubt, I'd use a User Defined Data Type instead of an array.  Although you'd probably have to fill it by looping through the recordset.